# React don't change state after first method trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my React app i have components structure:
-AllElements
--SingleElement
--SingleElementDetails

I am passing method `See` to `SingleElement` component where I invoke  `seefunc` to invoke see method from `AllElements` component. The problem i my state (name) in `AllElements` not change after first onClick trigger, it changes after secund click. Could you tell my why ?

```
    class AllElements extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                myData: [],
                viewingElement: {
                    name:""
                }
            }
             this.see = this.see.bind(this);
            console.log('Initial Sate',this.state.viewingElement);
        }


         see(name) {
        this.setState({
          viewingElement: {
            name:name
          }
        });
        console.log('State after SEE',this.state.viewingElement);
      }

        render() {
            const { myData, viewingElement } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            {myData.map(se => (
              <SingleElement
                key={se.id}
                name={se.name}
                see={this.see}
              />
            ))}
              <SingleElementDetails viewingElement={viewingElement}/>
          </div>
        );
        }
    }



    class SingleElement extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    seefunc(name) {
        this.props.see(this.props.name);
        console.log('Name in seefunc props',this.props.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.seefunc.bind(this)}>
                DIV CONTENT
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here is that `setState` is asynchronous. It does work the first time but you do not see it in your `console.log` because the `console.log` happens before the state is updated.

To see the updated state use the second argument of `setState` which is a callback function (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
 this.setState({
          viewingElement: {
            name:name
          }
        }, () => {
  console.log('State after SEE',this.state.viewingElement);
});
```

And in `SingleElement` use the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops)` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) method from react lifecycle to see the updated props:

```
seefunc(name) {
        this.props.see(this.props.name);
    }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
        console.log('Name in props',nextProps.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It *does* change. However `setState` is an aync process so you're only logging the *previous* state to the console. `setState` [does provide a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that allows you to run code after the async process has finished, so you can do:

```
this.setState({
  viewingElement: {
    name:name
  }
}, () => console.log('State after SEE',this.state.viewingElement));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/936zha4r/2/)**